# Comparing Items From Two Files To Determine Which Elements Changed

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Im doing a comparison of data from two files (an old and new file). The files are similar except that the new file has items from the old file that have changed. I need to add the changed items to a changed list and the unchanged items to an unchanged list. I do this by searching for each item from the new file in the old file and comparing file elements. If the new item is found, it is added to the unchanged list, otherwise it is added to the changed list.

What I am trying to determine now is which item in the new file has changed. How can I determine this if the item was not found? Also, more than one element in the new file could be different from the old file.

Heres the snippet:

```
foreach (var newfileItem in NewFile)
{
    var checkitem = OldFile.FirstOrDefault(d => d.fileID == newfileItem.fileID && d.SysName == newfileItem.Sysname && d.SysCount == newfileItem.SysCount);
    if (checkitem == null) //item not found therefore something changed
    {
        //which item changed??
        changedlist.Add(checkitem);
    }
    else //item found, therefore unchanged
    {
        unchangedlist.Add(newfileItem);
    }
    checkitem = null;
}
```

Comment: Files don't contain elements. Are you talking about collections, such as lists or arrays? To check if files changed, you should use hash functions like md5. To compare arrays, there are plenty of built-in methods in the collections/list objects.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you use the word 'file' it appears to me that you've already done the part where you read the contents of the files. And I believe that `NewFile` and `OldFile` are lists of some class instances that represent the content of a line of a file.

So I'm going to name it `FileItem`, and will look something like this.

```
public class FileItem
{
    public int FileID { get; set; }
    public int SysCount { get; set; }
    public string SysName { get; set; }
}
```

And I think you essentially want to find out which are the items unique to `OldFile`, and which are the items unique to `NewFile` (and maybe what's common to both as well).

For this, I would first write an `EqualityComparer` so I can compare items in the two lists. From your code it appears that you consider two items equal if three properties of that class are equal. So I'm following along that logic.

```
public class FileComparer : IEqualityComparer<FileItem>
{
    public bool Equals(FileItem x, FileItem y)
    {
        return (x.FileID == y.FileID && x.SysCount == y.SysCount && x.SysName == y.SysName);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(FileItem obj)
    {
        unchecked
        {
            int hash = 17;
            if (obj != null)
            {
                hash = hash * 23 + obj.FileID.GetHashCode();
                hash = hash * 23 + obj.SysCount.GetHashCode();
                hash = hash * 23 + obj.SysName.GetHashCode();
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Now it's as easy as using `LINQ` methods `Except()` and `Intersect()` to get what you want.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<FileItem> OldFile = new List<FileItem>
    {
        new FileItem() { FileID = 1, SysCount = 100, SysName = "One" },
        new FileItem() { FileID = 2, SysCount = 200, SysName = "Two" },
        new FileItem() { FileID = 3, SysCount = 300, SysName = "Three" },
        new FileItem() { FileID = 4, SysCount = 400, SysName = "Four" },
        new FileItem() { FileID = 5, SysCount = 500, SysName = "Five" }
    };

    List<FileItem> NewFile = new List<FileItem>
    {
        new FileItem() { FileID = 1, SysCount = 100, SysName = "One" },
        new FileItem() { FileID = 200, SysCount = 200, SysName = "Two" },
        new FileItem() { FileID = 3, SysCount = 300, SysName = "Three" },
        new FileItem() { FileID = 400, SysCount = 400, SysName = "Four" },
        new FileItem() { FileID = 5, SysCount = 500, SysName = "Five" }
    };

    var onlyInNew = NewFile.Except(OldFile, new FileComparer());
    var onlyInOld = OldFile.Except(NewFile, new FileComparer());
    var commonToBoth = OldFile.Intersect(NewFile, new FileComparer());

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sach. I pretty much have a similar process to this. What I wanted to know really is which property of the class changed for example, did SysName or SysCount change in each instane